Meaning of "reeds" in "Fat City" by Leonard Gardner
Here is an excerpt from chapter 6 of the novel Fat City by Leonard Gardner.

Later in the night it began to rain. To Ernie the first patters were
like small sounds from Faye’s mouth. Her lips had been against his so
long that his mind was drifting among images of reeds wavering with
the delicate movements of her tongue.

Does the word "reeds" here mean "a type of tall plant" or "a thin piece of wood that is attached to a musical instrument"?

Do any of the characters play a musical instrument?

@PeterShor thank you. No. Does it seem metaphorical either way?

I haven't read the book, but it seems fairly clear that Ernie has a mental picture of reeds waving in the breeze. It's unlikely that he is thinking of the reed of a woodwind instrument.
